# How can I store multiple key pair values?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, shared, preference

I'm currently following a tutorial on storing data in a persistent way, so that it will stay on the device so you can use it in-between sessions.

The tutorial shows how the user can enter in a Name and phone number within the main activity then it will be passed onto the view contacts activity. This uses key-value pairs. This lets the user view their contacts, even when the app is re-started.

However, each time the user adds a name and a phone number within the main activity, the previous name and phone number is overwritten. Allowing me to only store one contact within my list, when I want to store all contacts that have been inputted.

Can anyone help?

**MainActivity.cs**

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Content;

namespace Contacts
{
    [Activity(Label = "Contacts", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@mipmap/icon")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);




            // Get our button from the layout resource,
            // and attach an event to it



            Button button = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.submitButton);

            button.Click += delegate
            {

                EditText nameBox = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.nameBox);
                string name = nameBox.Text;
                EditText phoneBox = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.phoneBox);
                string phone = phoneBox.Text;


                //add the new contact to the share preferrences

                var localContacts = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("MyContacts", FileCreationMode.Private);
                //Private file creation mode, which means that the data can't be accessed by any other app on the phone  

                var contactEdit = localContacts.Edit(); // takes the shared preferences and tells it that we want to edit


                //this uses KeyValue pairs
                contactEdit.PutString("Name", name);
                contactEdit.PutString("Phone", phone);
                contactEdit.Commit(); //writes the shared preferences to the device

                //contactEdit.PutStringSet()


                // create a toast notification to confirm the submission

                Android.Widget.Toast.MakeText(this, "Item Added", ToastLength.Short).Show();

                //clear the boxes of the text

                nameBox.Text = "";
                phoneBox.Text = "";




            };


            //Button viewContactButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.viewContactButton);

            //viewContactButton.Click += (sender, e) =>
            //{
            //   var intent = new Intent(this,)
            //    StartActivity(Intent);





            //};


            Button btnContactButton = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.viewContactButton);

            btnContactButton.Click += delegate {


                StartActivity(typeof(ViewContactsActivity));
            };






        }
    }
}
```

**ViewContactsActivity.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;

namespace Contacts
{
    [Activity(Label = "ViewContactsActivity")]

    public class ViewContactsActivity : ListActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.ViewContacts);

            // retrieve the information from shared preferences
            //referencing the same file
            var localContacts = Application.Context.GetSharedPreferences("MyContacts", FileCreationMode.Private);


            string name = localContacts.GetString("Name", null);
            string phone = localContacts.GetString("Phone", null);


            //call the constructor, to overrride the string to control how it looks when you display it

            Contact myContact = new Contact(name, phone);

            //create an array of items that will go in the list

            Contact[] contactList = { myContact };

            //add the list to the list adapter


            ListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<Contact>(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, contactList);

            //contact list is the item we want to display

        }
    }
}
```

using System;

**Contact.cs**

```
namespace Contacts
{
    class Contact
    {

        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PhoneNumber { get; set; }

        public Contact(string name, string phone)
        {

            Name = name;
            PhoneNumber = phone;
        }


        public override string ToString()
        {
            return Name + "" + PhoneNumber;
        }

        // this chooses how the information will be displayed

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, use SQLite for this purpose. Store the data into a table and retrieve the same dataset by using queries. [Link](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/data/databases/sqlite/) for SQLite database implementation.

Comment: You could try serializing it as a JSON string or some other data format, and then serialize it back to preferences

Comment: @Baksteen how, would I go about that? I'm very new to storing data in a persistent way, as this is the first tutorial that I've followed

Comment: I don't know really, I have no experience with Xamarin. Coudn't you just store the value as an array of phone numbers?

Comment: When you store values, you should use different key to store different value.

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT can you provide an example on how to do this?

Comment: When you add another contact, use a different key like "user2".

Comment: @YorkShen-MSFT what if you're unsure of how many you wish to add?

Answer (score 0):

@bamb094, hope this sample application will help in your case.

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/serialization-and-deserialization-in-c-sharp/